# Parsing user input with php forms

Tags: php, html, parsing

looking at this and while I understand it somewhat I am pretty new to php and I would like to perform a similar parse , I wish to take user input (both numbers and words) and parse based on A.whether the string element is a word or number B.if the word is a certain word .. An example would be

"3 dogs Collie" is the form input , 
my ideal resolution would be to split this into 
3
Dog
and Collie

I have not started coding as I am new to php however my inital idea will be to search the string and if the element matches the predefined variable e.g "3" or "dog" then to extract this and place it in a new variable

any help would be really helpful thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is but it is entirely possible to split the string "3 dogs collie" and search it for specific words and then store the result in variables.

Comment: There are a large number of string functions available. This one ought to get you started: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help you : http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$tab = explode(' ',$yourInputValue);
// $tab[0] -> 3
// $tab[1] -> dogs
// $tab[2] -> collie
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that would help you get on your feet: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

```
$keywords = preg_split("/[\s]+/", "3 dogs Collie");
print_r($keywords);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => dogs
    [2] => Collie
)
```

To display '3 Dogs and Collie', just use this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

```
$format = "%d %s and %s";
echo sprintf($format, $keywords[0], ucfirst($keywords[1]), $keywords[2]);
```

Outputs:

```
3 Dogs and Collie
```